# Image texture won't show on object 3D viewport

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

I'm new to blender and having trouble showing my image texture on the object which is a .dae.
When I first imported it and selected the rig it already had the material and nodes attached with the diffuse and specular pngs selected.
When I see other tutorials showing how to add texture and render, whenever the base color node is attached to the principle the texture on the object shows, and I've tried viewing it in rendered mode however it is blank.

Could anyone help me with getting the texture to show on the object?

[image: shader editor and my 3d viewport]

Comment: Try `[z]` and then `[2]`. Or the third orb (viewport shading; material preview) from left in your 3D-view toolbar.

Comment: @gilu This is what shows up when I try material preview.                                                                                                [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHraE.png

Comment: It looks like you haven't UV-unwrapped it. This might get you started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM
What happens if you just add a color? Mute texture nodes by selecting and pressing `[m]`.

Comment: I tried UV-unwrapping (I think) by following the video yet it still doesn't show on rendered or 3D view. I also tried changing the base color yet nothing happens.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiuAj.png                              https://i.stack.imgur.com/r594H.jpg

Comment: @gilu sorry forgot to @ you

Comment: it looks like you're still missing the mapping node for your texture vector. And the image with the color; it's hard to see in edit mode. And still, you're not in material preview mode (3rd orb from left). If all else fails, please attach your .blend file.

Comment: So I did in fact actually try everything and preview it in material preview mode several times. It's just not selected in the image attached. I'm going to add my .blend file as I've tried the mapping node and nothing seemed to work. @gilu                  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1xEznQmv" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1xEznQmv/)

Comment: as you can see in this picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyh1x.jpg) I added some brick texture to your model (your's wasn't packed in the .blend file). I just added a UV-Map node, hit Z-2. That was it...

Comment: I tried copying exactly what you did @gilu and nothing showed up still, I'm going to try and reinstall blender and try different older versions.

Comment: @gilu I tried other versions and still same issue, when I try adding a normal base colour it remains grey. Not sure what to do since it seems to work for you but not for me.

Comment: Is it possible for you to send me your version of the .blend file so I can try and substitute my image for yours and see if it works?

Comment: It is ugly, but you'll get the idea:
[Blender-File](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Vye6OxPQ/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.
It's an issue to do with my AMD GPU Driver I think, since I've had issues with blender not opening due to my drivers before and I tried this on my macbook and it worked fine.
I set performance to high quality normals in render properties and it shows the textures now - in material preview before it would be blank. I saw somewhere that rolling back drivers would help so I'll try that as well.

Thank you @gilu for your help though!